# how to let cmake explicit link shared library

Tags: hyperlink, cmake, version, shared

the whole work directory is a shared folder on windows, i can't make symbol link

link libactivemq-cpp.so.20 with specified suffix .20

```
set (extra_libs libactivemq-cpp.so.20)
```

link the lib to the executable, but link error

```
target_link_libraries (voiceserver  ${extra_libs})

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lactivemq-cpp
```

i have tried rename `libactivemq-cpp.so.20` to `libactivemq-cpp.so` but get a running error , can't load `libactivemq-cpp.so.20`

Comment: .so shared object is a library type for use on a *nix platform. It is not possible to use them on windows.

Comment: the problem is not building on windows, i was using mount -t cifs //windows/folder ./workdir, where i can't make symbol link. the problem is how can i let to make  link the so.x.x.x with its suffix

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-ldl -lrt -pthread -l:libactivemq-cpp.so.20 -Wl,-rpath,.")
```